# Is it okay to use JwtBearerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata=false in production when behind a Reverse Proxy?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I have an angular application that communicates with a .Net Core REST API. I also have an authorization server that is installed on the same server as the API. The API validates the authorization token it receives from angular against the authorization server.

My plan was to set everything up behind a reverse proxy so that internal communication happens over http between the API and the authorization server in order to simplify the management of the certificates since there will be multiple instances of the services. External access would still happen over https.

In order to to do this I need to set the RequireHttpsMetadata property in JwtBearerOptions to False, but the documentation says that this should always be True when used in production. But considering that in my case the communication happens internally would it be okay if it's false?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same issue and found [a github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1825) discussing this same scenario.

The comments and code link there indicate that it validates the https connection for downloading metadata documents. So your reverse proxy should not impact this process and it should be left as **true** for security reasons.